# Organization specific settings for Office 365 add-in

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I am looking for an advice on how to store Outlook add-in settings specific to each organization. The settings include custom text to be used in the add-in, custom image. The add-in is line of business application that will deployed to multiple organizations in Office 365 and on-premise Exchange servers.

Is there any recommended way how such settings can be deployed and stored per organization basis?

Comment: Will the user be authenticating themselves within the add-in?

Comment: User will be using Outlook OWA, so I think it means "yes" - they will need to authenticate before using add-in functionality.

Comment: Logging into Outlook is different from logging into your add-in. Are you kicking off authentication when your add-in starts?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. No, I'm not kicking off any authentication. If a user has access to OWA, one also can use the add-in. The settings/confuguration that I need to implement is not user specific, but applies to entire organization (e.g. company logo).

Comment: Thank you. Are your customers hosting the add-in and manifest or merely side-loading the manifest you provide?

Comment: Most likely customers will be hosting the add-in themselves. However, side-loading might be handy in the future. So I would appreciate any feedback for both scenarios.

Comment: If they're hosting the add-in themselves, I would just put the settings into a config file for the web app. It wouldn't make sense to get to clever for a single-tenant application.

Comment: Yes, settings file was my idea as well for on-premise deployments. What about scenario when the add-in is side-loaded and hosted on our webserver? I could imagine creating central settings storage which could be queried based on customer id, but that sounds complex to me. Any better ideas how it can be implemented? Is it possible to leverage existing Office infrastructure (e.g. group policy, AD, etc.)? Sorry for being vague. I'm quite new to add-in development.